# Copy html elements to shadow dom

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I have a question how can I add existing elements to shadow dom. I have list of elements/components mostly form elements in slot and I want to have them in shadow dom of my component. I need all bindings also to be copied is it possible? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The `<slot>` element can help with this. It allows you to "project" user's content into a shadow root.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#composition_slot